# Differences of components missing from OpenJDK-17 (Eclipse Temurin) which was present in OracleJDK-11

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, adoptopenjdk, java-17

Please help me to know the key differences of components missing from OpenJDK-17 (Eclipse Temurin) which was present in OracleJDK-11.

Comment: There is nothing missing. Java is backward compatible.

Comment: See https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/17/apidiff/11/ In addition, when using reflection, Java 17 is more restrictive than Java 16 which is more restrictive than Java 15.

Comment: @MirekPluta Unfortunately, this is no longer true since Java 9. A couple of things has been first deprecated and then removed from the system library, and newer versions have become more restrictive in terms of encapsulation.

Answer (score 4):

[The Java Version Almanac **javaalmanac.io**](https://javaalmanac.io) provides comparisons between different Java versions of the things that have been added or removed to the **system library**: see [**Java 17 vs. Java 11**](https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/17/apidiff/11/).

See also the **release notes** of removed features and options of Java 12 to 17:

- [Java 12 - Removed Features and Options](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/12-relnote-issues.html#Removed)
- [Java 13 - Removed Features and Options](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/13-relnote-issues.html#Removed)
- [Java 14 - Removed Features and Options](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/14-relnote-issues.html#Removed)
- [Java 15 - Removed Features and Options](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-relnote-issues.html#Removed)
- [Java 16 - Removed Features and Options](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/16-relnote-issues.html#Removed)
- [Java 17 - Removed Features and Options](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17-relnote-issues.html#Removed)

Please also note the **Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals** ([JEP 396](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/396) and [JEP 403](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403)): when using reflection, Java 17 is more restrictive than Java 11.